# Move file from one folder to another folder in Denodo

Tags: denodo

I am processing some source CSV files using Denodo VDP and finally creating output files using Denodo Scheduler.
After processing the source files, i want to archive source files into different folders by moving to another file. I searched upon in Denodo but i could not find any option to do this.

Can some one help me with this archival requirement?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different things you can do here. If you want to stay within the Denodo Environment you can create a small java program to make the copy job (you have not enclosed any details about this so I can't help you a lot with how this script would look like).
This you can put into a stored procedure in denodo (take a look at the samples at DENODO_HOME\samples\vdp\storedProcedures). Add this stored procedure in your vdb (New -> Stored Procedure) and make a selection view based on that. This you can trigger from scheduler.

If you don't want to write java code for the copy/delete you can also run a batch/shell script from the stored procedure or try to use the Denodo SSH Custom Wrapper from DenodoCeonnect, if you have access to that.